# Performance issue in converting Java object to JSON String for the 1st time, its working fine the 2nd time

Tags: json

I need to convert a Java object to JSON String, its working quite fast(25 milliseconds) in 1 case, and very slow in another case(2000 milliseconds). This is the piece of code:

```
public AuditTrailDetails createAuditTrailDetails(String propertyName, Object oldValue, Object newValue, AuditTrail entity) throws IOException {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = policyManagerObjectMapper.getObjectMapper();
    String oldValueAsJSON = null;
    String newValueAsJSON = null;

    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    oldValueAsJSON = (oldValue != null) ? objectMapper
        .writeValueAsString(oldValue) : null;
    long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    log.info("Time taken to convert old value into string is: " + (endTime - startTime));

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    newValueAsJSON = (newValue != null) ? objectMapper
        .writeValueAsString(newValue) : null;
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    log.info("Time taken to convert new value into string is: " + (endTime - startTime));
}

@Component public class PolicyManagerObjectMapperImpl implements PolicyManagerObjectMapper {

private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

@Override
public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
 return objectMapper;
}
}
```

Comment: This createAuditTrailDetails is being called from 2 places in the code. In the 1st case, oldValue is being passed the object to convert and newValue is passed null. It takes lots of time(2000 milliseconds) to convert. In the 2nd case, oldValue is passed null, and newValue is passed the object to convert. It is quite fast(25 milliseconds) to convert. And this iteration is for 2000 times.

Comment: Another thing to mention is the size of the converted json string is 28 kb(when it is fast) and 14kb(when it is slow), so its actually the reverse. And the format of the json is exactly same, its just that the amount of data is doubled.
    
    I am not getting why it is happening.